# Is there way to disable singleplayer campaign score?

Tags: battlefield-4

In campaign every kill is rewarded with points. 100 - kill, +25 - headshot/knife, etc.

Is there way to disable display of this score?

I want to play the story, not an arcade with high scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried all the options in the Options menu and it appears to be impossible. And I agree with you, when I first started playing the campaign it irked me a bit that the scores kept loitering on my screen. It is unfortunate, but what can you expect from EA :/